# Direct product of rings and its automorphisms

Tags: ring-theory, direct-product

What are all the possible automorphisms over a direct product of rings? Are there any way to prove that they are the only ones?

Comment: The endomorphisms of direct products of rings look like matrices whose entries are ring homomorphisms, the invertible matrices will be the automorphisms. I think, without extra conditions on the rings, it is in general difficult to tell the structure of the automorphism group.

Comment: If you consider the additive basis as the ring's generators, invertible matrices should give the number of group automorphisms, but we do not know whether it preserves multiplication also..